# MEF. Вопрос по расширяемости?

Tags: c#, .net

Я только начинаю разбираться с MEF. Задача такая. Есть приложение, которое обрабатывает данные. Данные берутся из базы. Но я не уверен в выборе базы, поэтому решил предусмотреть расширяемость и возможность выбора нужной базы. Искал, как такое осуществить, выбор пал на MEF. Но мне не все ясно.

- Как в стороннем проекте (при написании плагина) получить интерфейс, который нужно реализовать?
- Откуда в плагине взять типы данных, используемые в проекте? Ну, например плагин должен вернуть некий объект типа MyClass. Откуда плагин должен взять его конструктор и тд?
- Можно ли написать плагин вне фрэймворка?

Comment: А зачем у вас база? Я вот использую хибернейт, который из коробки умеет кучу СУБД и не задумываюсь над плагинами\MEF.

Comment: @Monk, плагины мне не только для базы понадобятся. Еще, например, для парсинга документов в текст (doc, docx, pdf, html)

Answer (score 1):

Не ответ, но скорее вопрос к вам по теме.

А вы уверены что здесь вам подойдёт именно MEF?
Насколько я знаю, при работе с MEF у вас будет довольно сильная изоляция между хостом и плагинами. Это удобно для каких-то крупных вещей -- например, IDE и плагины к ней, когда плагин цепляющийся через MEF отвечает сразу за много вещей.
Для случая когда нужно развязаться по нескольким интерфейсам это будет слишком громоздко.

Посмотрите в сторону фреймворков Inversion of Control (IoC) and Dependency Injection (DI), например, [Unity](https://unity.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Не понимаю. В каком плане громоздко? Там же только объявление интерфейса, его реализация на стороне плагина и несколько атрибутов для импорта/экспорта. Все, кроме атрибутов мне и так придется делать. Так почему бы не развернуть это в MEF?